# Abstract Android screen to 320x480 dp?

Tags: android, screen-resolution

is there something I could do to tell the Android that it should abstract the whole screen to 320x480 dp?

Yes, I'm porting an iOS app.

Comment: if it is Web Application app. we can mention that in  meta tag..

Comment: Your question is ambiguous and your reasoning might be flawed.  Does the iOS app only support 320x480 (I suspect that you also mean pixels, not DP)?  Do you want to support all Android resolutions?  How will the app look on a 2560x1600 10 inch tablet?  Etc...

Comment: It's not a web app. It's a native app. Like you say there are many devices with many sizes. Instead of making an app for every possible screen ratio and resolution I thought it would be easier to wrap my 320x480 (or whatever) to the screen's actual size. I mean DP because this is still the logical size of iPhone / iPod touch screens no matter the resolution. Oh wait the iPhone 5 is bigger but you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

By using dp, you are already told Android to convert the pixels based on 320x480

320x480 is the baseline of dp, which means 320dp x 480dp = 320px x 480px on mdpi devices.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here, I think it should help http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html

EDIT - I actually meant to point you [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html), but you could reach it from the link above, too

I don't know if you have troubles reading the links or whatever, but here is the necessary part taken from the second link

> **Supporting Different Densities**
>
> This lesson shows you how to support different screen densities by
>   providing different resources and using resolution-independent units
>   of measurements.
>
> Use Density-independent Pixels One common pitfall you must avoid when
>   designing your layouts is using absolute pixels to define distances or
>   sizes. Defining layout dimensions with pixels is a problem because
>   different screens have different pixel densities, so the same number
>   of pixels may correspond to different physical sizes on different
>   devices. Therefore, when specifying dimensions, always use either dp
>   or sp units. A dp is a density-independent pixel that corresponds to
>   the physical size of a pixel at 160 dpi. An sp is the same base unit,
>   but is scaled by the user's preferred text size (it’s a
>   scale-independent pixel), so you should use this measurement unit when
>   defining text size (but never for layout sizes).
>
> For example, when you specify spacing between two views, use dp rather
>   than px:

```
 <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="@string/clickme"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

Comment: What I mean is if I abstract the screen to width 320, then 0 dp would be the extreme left and 320 would be the extreme right. Porting an existing app would be simple(r) instead of going back to design phase/table.

Comment: And that's exactly why I pointed you to the second link, where it shows you how to make use of device independent units (DP).

Comment: It would be helpful to know if anyone of us has actually answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the output in your **device** with the dimension 320 X 480, you can directly run the app from your project. By default, the android project is always suitable for 320 X 480 dimensions. If you want this in emulator, go to **AVD manager**, create a new emulator and in the **skin** section, choose the **Built in** as **HVGA** type. You will get this. 
Thanks.